# Importing table from SQL Server database into Powerquery

Tags: sql-server-2012, powerquery

I'm new to PowerQuery, I'm trying to import a table from a SQL Server database, but I always find cells that contain the word `[value]` or `[table]`, what does that mean?

[image: sql server db into powerquery]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns with `[Table]` and `[Value]` cells represent foreign keys to another table. If you edit the query, you can click on the arrow next to the column name to select the fields from those related tables you want to include in your current table.